# How to add protocol prefix in Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, yaml, environment-variables

In my Kubernetes cluster, I have a ConfigMap object containing the address of my Postgres pod. It was created with the following YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-configmap
data:
  database_url: postgres-service
```

Now I reference this value in one of my Deployment's configuration:

```
env:
 - name: DB_ADDRESS
   valueFrom:
     configMapKeyRef:
       name: postgres-configmap
       key: database_url
```

This deployment is a Spring Boot application that intends to communicate with the database. Thus it reads the database's URL from the DB_ADDRESS environment variable. (ignore the default values, those are used only during development)

```
datasource:
    url: ${DB_ADDRESS:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users}
    username:  ${POSTGRES_USER:postgres}
    password:  ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:mysecretpassword}
```

So, according to the logs, the problem is that the address has to have the `jdbc:postgresql://` prefix. Either in the ConfigMap's YAML or in the application.yml I would need to concatenate the prefix protocol string with the variable. Any idea how to do it in yml or suggestion of some other workaround?

Comment: Why don't you just put the full database url in your ConfigMap?

Comment: @larsks Well, I guess in the ConfigMap the "postgres-service" value gets dynamically replaced by Kubernetes depending on what ClusterIP the Postgres pod actually has.

Comment: That's not how services and configmaps work at all (unless you're using some sort of automation that you haven't mentioned in your question). First, you need to create a Service for you postgres Pod. Then set `database_url` in your ConfigMap to `jdbc:postgresql://postgreshost:5432/users`, except replace `postgreshost` with the *name* of the Service resource you've created for your postgres service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), that will provide you with a hostname (the name of the service) that you can then use in the ConfigMap. E.g., if you create a service named `postgres`, then your ConfigMap would look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-configmap
data:
  database_url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/users
```

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes environment variable declarations can [embed the values of other environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/).  This is the only string manipulation that Kubernetes supports, and it pretty much only works in `env:` blocks.

For this setup, once you've retrieved the database hostname from the ConfigMap, you can then embed it into a more complete `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable:

```yaml
env:
 - name: DB_ADDRESS
   valueFrom:
     configMapKeyRef:
       name: postgres-configmap
       key: database_url
 - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
   value: 'jdbc:postgresql://$(DB_ADDRESS):5432/users'
```

You might similarly parameterize the port (though it will almost always be the standard port 5432) and database name.  Avoid putting these settings in a Spring profile YAML file, where you'll have to rebuild your application if any of the deploy-time settings change.

Comment: `'jdbc:postgresql://$(DB_ADDRESS):5432/users'` is not valid and won't work.